# phpmyadmin: create a function

Tags: function, phpmyadmin

i'm trying to create a function in my phpmyadmin - doesnt work .. :/
here's my syntax:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION fixString(input varchar) RETURNS varchar
BEGIN
  declare output varchar;
  SET output = REPLACE(input,'ö','oe');
  RETURN output;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') RETURNS varchar BEGIN declare output varchar; SET output = ' at line 1

any ideas what's wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `VARCHAR`, so you have to indicate a max size:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION fixString(input varchar(15)) RETURNS varchar(15)
BEGIN
  declare output varchar(15);
  SET output = REPLACE(input,'ö','oe');
  RETURN output;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```