# MySQL: Create and USE a function in phpmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a MySQL function in phpMyadmin. I've watched youtube videos and looked up all kinds of resources around the web and nothing is working. I found another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024730/phpmyadmin-create-a-function) but apparently there's something that I'm missing.

I modified that case to my table and can't get it to run. This is what I'm trying and below it is the error code. Without the delimiter // it says there's a syntax error at '' on line 1.

```
//
CREATE FUNCTION fixString (first varchar(27)) RETURNS varchar(27)
BEGIN
  declare output varchar(27);
  SET output = REPLACE(first,'a','A');
  RETURN output;
END //

SELECT fixstring(first) FROM customerList

###########################Error##################################
Error
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 1
STR: //
SQL: //
CREATE FUNCTION fixString (first varchar(27)) RETURNS varchar(27)
BEGIN
  declare output varchar(27);//
CREATE FUNCTION fixString (first varchar(27)) RETURNS varchar(27)
BEGIN
  declare output varchar(27);//
CREATE FUNCTION fixString (first varchar(27)) RETURNS varchar(27)
BEGIN
  declare output varchar(27);//
CREATE FUNCTION fixString (first varchar(27)) RETURNS varchar(27)
BEGIN
  declare output varchar(27);//
CREATE FUNCTION fixString (first varchar(27)) RETURNS varchar(27)
BEGIN
  declare output varchar(27);

SQL query:

// CREATE FUNCTION fixString (first varchar(27)) RETURNS varchar(27) BEGIN declare output varchar(27);

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//
CREATE FUNCTION fixString (first varchar(27)) RETURNS varchar(27)
BEGIN
  ' at line 1
```

Alternatively, thinking maybe phpmyAdmin is the problem I tried sqlfiddle. If you could show me how to make that one work I would appreciate the understanding.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04403/1

Comment: Remove the //, add :
DELIMITER # before the CREATE FUNCTION. # after the END of the function. Then DELIMITER ; so the ; is the DELIMITER again

Comment: I tried and it said something about not being DETERMINISTIC or some other stuff, so it didn't create the function. When I added the statement DETERMINISTIC before BEGIN it worked. I'll read up on what that means.

Comment: DETERMINISTIC is the same answer on the same input parameters always. (1+1=deterministic, RANDOM+1=not deterministic. Your function seems deterministic to me).